# Maximum character to Item Description in Fedex Label creation

Tags: c#, fedex

I am trying to connect to the FedEx shipping webservice for creating ship labels. I want to add Item Description to CreatePendingShipmentRequest as

```
request.RequestedShipment.RequestedPackageLineItems[counter].ItemDescription=""myvalue";
```

I want to know the maximum character limit that I can pass to this request element.

Answer (score 0):

May this following code will help you.

```
$request['RequestedShipment'] = array(
    'ShipTimestamp' => date('c'),
    'DropoffType' => 'REGULAR_PICKUP', // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, DROP_BOX, BUSINESS_SERVICE_CENTER and STATION
    'ServiceType' => $GLOBALS['PRIORITY_INDEX'], // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER
    'PackagingType' => 'YOUR_PACKAGING', // valid values FEDEX_BOX, FEDEX_PAK, FEDEX_TUBE, YOUR_PACKAGING,                                      
    'LabelSpecification' => addLabelSpecification(),
    'CustomerSpecifiedDetail' => array('MaskedData'=> 'SHIPPER_ACCOUNT_NUMBER'), 
    'RateRequestTypes' => array('ACCOUNT'), // valid values ACCOUNT and LIST
    'PackageCount' => 1,                                       
    'RequestedPackageLineItems' => array(
        '0' => addPackageLineItem1()
    )
);
```

You will try your package count as 1.

Find the below link, we can know the Fedex Shipping Intergrations maxlength for all paramaters.

**http://www.fedex.com/us/account/fbo/downloadref.pdf**